# Why is there lag sometimes when installing npm packages?

Tags: npm

I ran `npm i -g n-letter-wordle`. I already have this version of `n-letter-wordle` installed, yet it still took 59 seconds to update:

[image]

Then I run the exact same command and it only takes 245ms:

[image]

What is the issue with NPM causing the slowness of the first call? Why does the NPM CLI take a full minute to do nothing?

Comment: Try adding a `--loglevel verbose`, NPM might tell you what it's doing.